# slick.js -- what's supposed to happen if you only have 1 image in the carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, slick.js

I am using Meteor and slick.js (atmosphere package udondan:slick) to display a carousel of images and dynamically populating the carousel with a list of divs.

I'm finding that if I have 2+ images, the images are typically centered nicely and it seems to work correctly.

But if I only happen to have 1 image in the carousel, the image is not centered and instead is left justified.

I'm also seeing an issue when I use bootstrap tabs with a slick.js carousel in each tab with each carousel having 2+ images (each carousel has a unique id so they load correctly), when I click on a tab to make the carousel visible it initially loads the first image left justified but once I start to page through the images it self corrects and centers the images.

Curious if anyone has run into either issue before and if there's any suggested workarounds?